# Kindly Someone suggest how to bind datepicker value in my form using ng-model

Tags: angular, angular6, angular4-forms, ngx-bootstrap

Here's `datepicker.ts`

```
import { Component, HostListener, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { BsDatepickerDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';

@Component({
    selector: 'demo-date-picker-hide-on-scroll',
    templateUrl: './datepicker-popup.html'
})

export class DemoDatepickerHideOnScrollComponent {

    @ViewChild(BsDatepickerDirective) datepicker: 
    BsDatepickerDirective;

    @HostListener('window:scroll')
        onScrollEvent() {
        this.datepicker.hide();
    }
}
```

and `datepicker.html`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-12 col-md-9 form-group">
      <input
        placeholder="Datepicker"
        class="form-control"
        #dp="bsDatepicker"
        bsDatepicker>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have added datepicker component. It's working fine. I'm getting
    datepicker in my form but, I'm not able to bind my datepicker value
    using `[(ngModel)]`. Please, someone suggest the way to get the value in
    my console.

Comment: The question is old but it might help someone else, if `FormsModule` is  not imported where this component resides you can't use `ngModel`. Just after importing FormsModule it'll work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **ngModel** with following ways,

```
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-12 col-md-9 form-group">
          <input
            placeholder="Datepicker"
            class="form-control"
            #dp="bsDatepicker"
            bsDatepicker [ngModel]="date"
            (ngModelChange)="date = $event.toLocaleDateString()">
        </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-12 col-md-9 form-group">
          <input
            placeholder="Datepicker"
            class="form-control"
            #dp="bsDatepicker"
            bsDatepicker [ngModel]="date"
            (ngModelChange)="($event.toLocaleDateString())=>{this.date=new Date($event.toLocaleDateString())}">
        </div>
     </div>
```